# Estoy aprendiendo django y no se mucho lo que estoy haciendo pero este es el error al cargarlo en el navegador

Tags: python, django, sqlite3

Using the URLconf defined in Proyecto1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
saludo/
```

The current path, saludo2, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Tanto el título como la pregunta deben estar en el idioma de [es.so].